# how to pass 'web socket (Socket.Io) to certain screens (not a chat app)

Tags: javascript, react-native, socket.io, expo

i am having trouble passing Socket.Io socket to certain screens in my react native app, I want to share the socket with the navigation (like a prop I think I am not sure). Does someone have any suggestions on how to do it? I tried to use this approach(https://dev.to/bravemaster619/how-to-use-socket-io-client-correctly-in-react-app-o65) on react native and it didn't work.
I am open to ideas and my main goal is to share the same socket with two pages after the signin/signup and to send a token to confirm the user when the socket is making the connection.

app.js-

```
import React from 'react';
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import { setNavigator } from './src/navigationRef';
import AccountScreen from './src/screens/AccountScreen';
import SigninScreen from './src/screens/SigninScreen';
import SignupScreen from './src/screens/SignupScreen';
import ProductDetailScreen from './src/screens/ProductDetailScreen';
import ProductListScreen from './src/screens/ProductListScreen';
import AddProductScreen from './src/screens/AddProductScreen';
import ResolveAuthScreen from './src/screens/ResolveAuthScreen';
import { Provider as AuthProvider } from './src/context/AuthContext';
import { Provider as ProductProvider } from './src/context/ProductDetailContext';
import { SocketContext, socket} from './src/context/SocketContext';

import { FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons';

const PlnatListFlow = createStackNavigator({
  ProductList:ProductListScreen,
  ProductDetail: ProductDetailScreen,
});
PlnatListFlow.navigationOptions = {
  title: 'ProductList',
  tabBatIcone: <FontAwesome name="th-list" size={20} />,
};
const switchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  ResolveAuth: ResolveAuthScreen,
  loginFlow: createStackNavigator({
    Signup: SignupScreen,
    Signin: SigninScreen,
  }),
  mainFlow: createBottomTabNavigator({
    PlnatListFlow: PlnatListFlow,
    AddProduct: AddProductScreen,
    Account: AccountScreen,
  }),
});

const App = createAppContainer(switchNavigator);

export default () => {
  return (
   <SocketContext.Provider value={socket}>
    <ProductProvider>
      <AuthProvider>
        <App
          ref={(navigator) => {
            setNavigator(navigator);
          }}
        />
      </AuthProvider>
    </ProductProvider>
  </SocketContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

SocketContext.js-

```
import React from 'react';
import io from "socket.io-client";
import {url} from '../api/Config';

export const socket = io(url, {
  transports: ["websocket"],
 // upgrade:false,
});

export const SocketContext = React.createContext();
```